# Derivatives and distribution function

Tags: calculus, statistics

I will try to ask the question as succintly as possible. I think there is some easy definition and trick that I am not seeing:

Suppose $u\sim F[\underline{u},\bar{u}]$ with distribution function $F$ and density $f$.

And $m=1-F(u)$, how can I prove that:

$$\dfrac{\partial \left( \int_u^{\bar{u}}xdF(x)\right)}{\partial m} = u$$

**Edit:** just for completeness I add a reference https://publications.ut-capitole.fr/id/eprint/31264/1/wp_tse_887revised.pdf at pag 12 derivation of equation 5

... Where can I learn how to work with these derivatives? also the other $\dfrac{\partial \left( -F(u) \hat{\Psi}(\theta_E , 1-F(u)) \right) }{\partial m}$ is very confusing to me

Comment: Is $u$ supposed to have a uniform distribution between some minimum $\underline{u}$ and some maximum $\bar{u}$?  Or something else?

Comment: "generic distribution function F that satisfies the standard monotone hazard rate condition."

Comment: $u\sim [\underline{u},\bar{u}]$ seems wrong. did you mean, $u \in [\underline{u},\bar{u}]$? \
Check the limits of the integral as well. Also check your first line, did you mean "answer" instead of "ask"

Comment: Please check the updated question. Limits of the integral are supposed to be like that because the issue here is to define the optimal $u$ that would maximize a function and the possible value must be $u\in [\underline{u},\bar{u}]$. I don't understand from the paper whether he does the derivative wrt $m$ or directly wrt $u$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have the chain rule:

$
\dfrac{\partial \left( \int_u^{\bar{u}}xdF(x)\right)}{\partial m} 
= \dfrac{\partial \left( \int_u^{\bar{u}}xdF(x)\right)}{\partial u} \cdot \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial m}
$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that $F'(x)=f(x)$:

$\dfrac{\partial \left( \int_u^{\bar{u}}xdF(x) \right)}{\partial u} 
= - \dfrac{\partial \left( \int_{\bar{u}}^{u}xf(x)dx \right)}{\partial u}
= - uf(u)
$

Also, by the theorem for derivative of the inverse,

$\dfrac{\partial m}{\partial u} = \dfrac{\partial(1-F(u))}{\partial u} = -f(u) 
\implies \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial m} = \dfrac{1}{-f(u)}$

Combining the three equations above, we have:

$
\dfrac{\partial \left( \int_u^{\bar{u}}xdF(x)\right)}{\partial m} 
= -uf(u) \cdot \dfrac{1}{-f(u)} = u
$

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the second step that need to properly understand. Could someone provide good readings/books/exercises/resources to review this particular topic?

Comment: @KArrow'sBest You can read about the fundamental theorem of calculus in any calculus book or on the internet, for example here: https://mathmistakes.info/facts/CalculusFacts/learn/doi/doi.html

Comment: @KArrow'sBest Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer as per community guidelines: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262057/acceptance-and-upvoting

Comment: I know the fund. th. of calculus but what confuses me is the $dF(x)$ part and the fact that the integral becomes in $dx$

Comment: $\dfrac{d F(x)}{d x}=f(x) \iff F(x) = f(x) dx $

Comment: @KArrow'sBest Yeah the reasons for that go into measure theory and the definitions of what integrating wrt $dF(x)$ mean; but you most likely only need to know $$\dfrac{d F(x)}{d x}=f(x) \iff dF(x) = f(x) dx$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140322/discussion-between-karrowsbest-and-whoisit).